# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when my splash screen starts

Tags: java, android

When my splash screen starts i get tis error in logcat:

```
11-06 02:36:45.450: E/global(4184): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
11-06 02:36:45.450: E/global(4184): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
11-06 02:36:45.450: E/global(4184):     at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
11-06 02:36:45.450: E/global(4184):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1280)
11-06 02:36:45.450: E/global(4184):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1247)
11-06 02:36:45.450: E/global(4184):     at com.example.kostas.splash$1.run(splash.java:38)
```

this is my class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
        Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                        sleep(100);
                        if(_active) {
                            waited += 100;
                        } 
                    }
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                } finally {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.kostas.main"));
                    stop();
                }
            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            _active = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

line 38 is stop();

My app starts with no problem but i would like to fix it..i tried to delete "stop();" but i m getting another error too..

```
11-06 02:44:56.321: E/(32599): onResume() check 0
11-06 02:44:56.321: E/(32599): onResume() check 1
11-06 02:44:56.321: E/Launcher(32599): setWindowOpaque()
11-06 02:44:56.341: E/(32599): onResume() check 2, mRestoring : false
11-06 02:44:56.341: E/(32599): onResume() check 3
11-06 02:44:56.341: E/(32599): onResume() check 4
11-06 02:44:56.345: E/(32599): onResume() check 5
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is in the error message: Thread.stop() is deprecated, and Android does not support deprecated methods.

Perhaps you can try using Thread.sleep() in your onCreate to do the timeout instead.

Comment: He is using `sleep()` to implement the timeout, the `stop()` is used after the timeout has completed, and is entirely unnecessary.  The thread will stop on its own when the `run()` method returns.

Comment: so i just have to delete stop(); ?

Comment: Yes, just delete the `stop()`.  A Thread stops naturally when `run()` exits.

Comment: I was having the same problem. I was naming my own functions as I saw fit and I haven't even considered the `Thread` object having a deprecated `stop()` method... why doesn't it say so? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Thread.stop()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29) has been deprecated for some time now:

> This method is inherently unsafe. Stopping a thread with Thread.stop
>   causes it to unlock all of the monitors that it has locked (as a
>   natural consequence of the unchecked ThreadDeath exception propagating
>   up the stack). If any of the objects previously protected by these
>   monitors were in an inconsistent state, the damaged objects become
>   visible to other threads, potentially resulting in arbitrary behavior.
>   Many uses of stop should be replaced by code that simply modifies some
>   variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running. The
>   target thread should check this variable regularly, and return from
>   its run method in an orderly fashion if the variable indicates that it
>   is to stop running. If the target thread waits for long periods (on a
>   condition variable, for example), the interrupt method should be used
>   to interrupt the wait.

In short, you should not be calling `stop()`.  If you add some details about what your other error is when you remove `stop()`, maybe someone can help with that one too.

Comment: Wow, bizarre. Deprecation is a prelude to deletion. Deprecation doesn't mean that you don't have to implement the method, it means that you should stop calling the method, because in a future Java version, it will be gone. I guess Google was telling the truth: Android really isn't Java.

Comment: That is correct, the JRE that runs on Android devices is a customized version of Java.  It is not the same as the implementation you get if you download from java.sun.com.  The same applies on Google App Engine as well.

Comment: IIRC, some of the deprecated Thread methods are not implemented even by Sun / Oracle JVMs.  I think that Google is doing the right thing here by stomping the rest of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
thread.stop() is deprecated method so you have to remove that line from your code.
```