# I am having error to open front camera using android

Tags: android, camera

I am working on android camera app,I want green screen chroma key effect to captured image. I have used http://code.google.com/p/chroma-key-project/downloads/list this chroma key project with my code.

I am using tablet which having front camera instead of back camera..I have also used permission for front camera

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
```

still it shows an error null pointer exception from preview.java page to this line . `camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);` // <9> why?

Check the `preview.java` page from the given link in chroma key project.please suggest.

this type of error I am getting.

10-11 15:37:36.131: W/dalvikvm(11339): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409ee1f8)
10-11 15:37:36.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 15:37:36.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11339): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
10-11 15:37:36.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11339):    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1076)
10-11 15:37:36.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11339):    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1063)
10-11 15:37:36.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11339):    at com.Activity.new2you4kids.MainClass.startCamera(MainClass.java:179)
10-11 15:37:36.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11339):    at com.Activity.new2you4kids.MainClass$1.handleMessage(MainClass.java:61)
10-11 15:37:36.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11339):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-11 15:37:36.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11339):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-11 15:37:36.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-11 15:37:36.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11339):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-11 15:37:36.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11339):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-11 15:37:36.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11339):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-11 15:37:36.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11339):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-11 15:37:36.141: E/AndroidRuntime(11339):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camera.open() tries to open the default back camera i think, so it returns null because there is no camera on the back.

what if you try the function Camera.open(int) to open the front camera?

Like this:

```
int getFrontCameraId() {
    CameraInfo ci = new CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
        if (ci.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) return i;
    }
    return -1; // No front-facing camera found
}
```

And get it like this:

```
int index = getFrontCameraId();
if (index == -1) error();
Camera c = Camera.open(index);
```

From: [How to detect if there is front camera and if there is how to reach and use front camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937718/how-to-detect-if-there-is-front-camera-and-if-there-is-how-to-reach-and-use-fron)

**Edit:** the code you are using is very old and has all kinds of old functions, the crash you are having is caused by an old thread function (stop) i think.

Code from the link:

```
  public void startCamera() {
        setContentView(R.layout.camview);
        fGameView = null;
        fGameThread.stop();
        fGameThread=null;
```

according to the developers site:

stop()
This method is deprecated. because stopping a thread in this manner is unsafe and can leave your application and the VM in an unpredictable state.

See:

[java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when my splash screen starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024434/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-when-my-splash-screen-starts)

[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29)

**Edit two:**

Change the onCreateOptionsMenu code to this, you should not use the myMenu variable.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, MENU_START, 0, R.string.menu_start);
    menu.add(0, MENU_SEND, 0, R.string.menu_send);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks i have used this code.but I am having java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException while opening front camera.why?

Comment: What api level are you using? And could you give me the full error? Cause this error could be caused by any thing.

Comment: hi I have solved that issue.I have used sleep instaead of stop.but I cant open menu options.send and restart.I am using Micromax funbook pro.why?

Comment: Is that because of the fact that your thread is sleeping and not responding? I'm not getting the point.

Comment: after capturing image we can open menu in that there are 2 options send and restart.so I cant see that options.

Comment: This should actually be another question but here is the answer is in the post above. Don't forget to accept answers if they helped you out with your question, this will help other people having the same question.