# Why is this code throwing a NullPointerException?

Tags: android, timer, handler

I'm trying to code a timer for Android, but I'm getting problems with the handler. This line:

```
handler.post(new Runnable(){
```

...is triggering a NullPointerException. Why?

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment  {

    private int stunde,minute,sekunde;
    private TextView textfield;
    private Button buttonStart,buttonStop;
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean Running = true;
    private Runnable runnable;
    private Thread thread;



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        buttonStart =(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonStop = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                thread.stop();

            }

        });
        textfield = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startZeit);





        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Running = true;
                runnable = new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        while(Running){
                            try{

                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            }
                            catch(InterruptedException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            handler.post(new Runnable(){


                                @Override
                                public void run(){

                                    sekunde+=1;


                                    if(sekunde == 60){
                                        minute +=1;
                                        sekunde = 0;
                                    }if(minute == 60){
                                        stunde +=1;
                                    }

                                    textfield.setText(String.format("%02d",stunde)+" : "+String.format("%02d", minute)+" : "+String.format("%02d",sekunde));



                                }


                            });
                        }

                    }


                };
                thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
            handler = new Handler();



            }

        });


        return rootView;
    }


}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't initialized the `handler` object. So you are getting a `NullPointerException` on it.

You will need to do some thing like that:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Somewhere in your code before you can use this object.

Comment: I done it ,beneath "thread.start();" -can you tell me where exactly i need to initialize it ?

Comment: Just move this line: handler = new Handler(); to another location. Do it right in the start of onCreateView. Or better yet put it in the onCreate method.

Comment: Thanks Emil, now he is telling me java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at thread.stop();

Comment: on what line you get that?

Comment: on line 36 at : thread.stop() in the onclicklistener from buttonStop

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024434/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-when-my-splash-screen-starts

Answer (score 0):

Your handler has to be instantiated with

```
 handler = new Handler();
```

**before** it is used.

Comment: That's the problem. You have to do it before.

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is quite hard to read but you get a NPE if runnable or handler have not been initialised. Since you are providing a new runnable object, that means your handler has not been initialised.

I think you are creating your handler inside an onClickListener. Try initialising it in onCreate or towards the top of onCreateView for clarity.

Goodluck